# Cannot make ng-repeat work with angular material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design

For some strange reason while trying to use Angular material with `ng-repeat` directive it prints nothing however `$scope.products` is a valid array. There is no errors in the console. What might be a reason?

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/ResilientJoe/pen/PNOQGq)

Comment: The order of ng-app and ng-controller seems off. I don't know if that is the reason but I do it the other way around in my projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found two problems, first: is the `forEach` you need to iterate and push your elements inside the forEach function. Second: is the ng-repeat you need to track by $index. Code running at: http://codepen.io/eduardonunesp/pen/JXOvby?editors=1001

Comment: There are duplicates. `forEach` suppose to update the array of products.

Answer (score 0):

**Works well:**

```
 $scope.products.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
      $scope.products[index]["price"] = $scope.getPrice(element);
    });
```